# No methods of read a file seem to work, all return nothing - C++

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

EDIT: Problem solved! Turns out Windows 7 wont let me read/ write to files without explicitly running as administrator. So if i run as admin it works fine, if i dont i get the weird results i explain below.

I've been trying to get a part of a larger program of mine to read a file.

Despite trying multiple methods(istream::getline, std::getline, using the >> operator etc) All of them return with either /0, blank or a random number/what ever i initialised  the var with.

My first thought was that the file didn't exist or couldn't be opened, however the state flags .good, .bad and .eof all indicate no problems and the file im trying to read is certainly in the same directory as the debug .exe and contains data.

I'd most like to use istream::getline to read lines into a char array, however reading lines into a string array is possible too.

My current code looks like this:

```
    void startup::load_settings(char filename[]) //master function for opening a file.
{

    int i = 0; //count variable
    int num = 0; //var containing all the lines we read.
    char line[5];


        ifstream settings_file (settings.inf);
        if (settings_file.is_open());
        {
            while (settings_file.good())
            {
                    settings_file.getline(line, 5);
                    cout << line;

            }
        }



    return;
}
```

As said above, it compiles but just puts /0 into every element of the char array much like all the other methods i've tried.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this code work with different files?

Comment: Note that the argument `filename` is not being used, `settings.inf` is being used instead. Is that correct?

Comment: Note there is a trailing semi-colon on the `if` which makes it useless and will give the impression the file was successfully opened and it might not have been. Fix this to be certain the file is being opened: `if (settings_file.is_open())`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code is not complete, what is `settings.inf` ?

Secondly most probably your reading everything fine, but the way you are printing is cumbersome

1. `cout << line;` where `char line[5];` be sure that the last element of the array is `\0`.
   You can do something like this.
   `line[4] = '\0'` or you can manually print the values of each element in array in a loop.
2. Also you can try printing the character codes in hex for example. Because the values (character codes) in array might be not from the visible character range of ASCII symbols. You can do it like this for example : 
   `cout << hex << (int)line[i]`

Comment: settings.inf is the file im attempting to open and read from. I'm not directly trying to print the output, it gets pushed to another function once the file is read, its printing just for debugging right now. although i'll have a look at printing the output better.

Comment: Good, then go over points 1 and 2 in my answer and provide a feedback if you still have problems.

Comment: You mean `line[4] = '\0';`.